AWS NoSql workbench: Dynamo DB not covering all data in PNG export
I have a dataset of a 100 rows in my demo DDB table, and when I try to export the PNG, it causes some strife.
I have an M2 MacBook Pro, and NoSql WB Version 3.12.1 (3.12.1)
The zipped png files are large (both in file size & image dimension)
but doesn't cover the window with all the data. It just takes a screencap of what is visible on my window and nothing else.
Any help from the community would be great!
Adding a sample screenshot of the PNG Export

Large columns - mostly empty
Large rows - mostly empty again

PS: I notice some articles mentioning that NoSQL Workbench is buggy, but not much else.

I have tried multiple things:

different configurations within the workbench,
combinations of of screen sizes connected to my Mac,
position of scrolling my data,
even reducing it to 10 items in multiple tables,

but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Whats the issue exactly? You can't fit 100 items into a screenshot?

Yes, nor even 10 items properly.. Adding some sample PNG exports to my post for context.

@ufo2mstar could you update to version 3.13.0 ? The latest version should export full view of the data model to PNG.
